# Convert String to Integer with multiplication with Python List

Tags: python

I have an output in which needs to be updated to convert decimals to a whole number, but it currently is located in a list.

Here is current output:

```
 s12,NONE,s11:1.7260924347106847|s17:1.7260924347106847|s14:0.6795961471815897|s10:0.6795961471815897|s19:0.6795961471815897|s13:0.6795961471815897|
 s14,NONE,s13:4.498681156950466|s11:1.7260924347106847|s17:1.7260924347106847|s12:0.6795961471815897|
```

This is what I need it to look like (notice the decimal after the colon above is x 100 and drop the decimals):

```
 s12,NONE,s11:172|s17:172|s14:67|s10:67|s19:67|s13:67|
 s14,NONE,s13:449|s11:172|s17:172|s12:67|
```

Here is where I'm at currently with the code:

```
filehandle = open(tempcsv, 'r')
for line in filehandle:
    fields = line.split(',')
    try:
        driver = fields[0]
        recs = fields[2].split('|')
        rec_str = ", ".join(recs)
        each_rec_colon = rec_str.split(':')
        rec_1 = each_rec_colon[0]
        print rec_1 # will obviously need to expand on this and then write back to file
    except:
        a = 0
```

Comment: So, whats the problem ?

Comment: To change the current decimals to the whole number you want, this is the math: print(int(n*100))

Comment: I think the line recs=fields[2]...and rec_str=",".join...is redundant ..you can achieve it replace function...secondly..in each_rec_colon you won't get the desired result because it will contain [s11, <anynum>s17,<anynum>s14...]

Comment: @fixxxer - i need the first output listed above to look like the second.  currently my code does not accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

Actually you didn't replaced any thing in your text instead you can use `re.sub` within a list comprehension :

```
>>> l=[[re.sub(r':(\d)\.(\d{2}).*',lambda x:':'+x.group(1)+x.group(2) if x.group(1)!='0' else ':'+x.group(2),li) for li in line.split('|')] for line in open(tempcsv, 'r')]
>>> ['|'.join(k) for k in l]
[' s12,NONE,s11:172|s17:172|s14:67|s10:67|s19:67|s13:67|', ' s14,NONE,s13:449|s11:172|s17:172|s12:67|']
```

The following regex

```
r':(\d)\.(\d{2}).*'
```

will detect a number that came after `:` then a dot them 2 digit then every thing as you need the the int number and 2 of decimals you can put them within a capture group then replaced them in your text based on a costume condition.

For better understanding i expand the list comprehension here :

```
with open(tempcsv, 'r') as f :
    for line in f:
               subs=[re.sub(r':(\d)\.(\d{2}).*',lambda x:':'+x.group(1)+x.group(2) if x.group(1)!='0' else ':'+x.group(2),li) for li in line.split('|') ]
               print '|'.join(subs) f
```

You can also use a separate function like following :

```
>>> def replacer(m):
...   g=m.group(1)
...   if g!=0:
...       return ':'+g+m.group(2)
...   else :
...       return ':'+m.group(2)

with open(tempcsv, 'r') as f :
    for line in f:
               subs=[re.sub(r':(\d)\.(\d{2}).*',replacer,li) for li in line.split('|') ]
               print '|'.join(subs) f
```

Comment: I don't think sticking it all in a list comprehension is a very good idea.

Comment: @jKraut what part is vague?

Comment: It would be clearer to use a separate function as the `repl` argument to `re.sub`, too, rather than a `lambda` expression.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes i was doing that!;)

Comment: ...why `lambda x: replacer(x)` rather than `replacer`?!

Answer (score 0):

You simply open two files, one for reading and another for writing.

For each line in input file, we split it on `","` which would give us 3 fields and e catch them with 3 variables as `rec_1, rec_2, rec_3`, We also remove the trailing `"|"`, using `.strip()` method character as it will later interrupt in splitting the data.

Then we split the third variable on `"|"` and again split on `":"` to get 2 strings, then casting the second string as float, multiplying it with factor (100) and at last again concatenating the results together.

```
with open("testing.txt", "r") as data, open("testing2.txt", "w") as out_file:
   wrt = ""
   for line in data.readlines():
      rec_1, rec_2, rec_3 = line.strip("|").split(",")
      wrt += rec_1+","+rec_2+","
      for rec in rec_3.split("|"):
         a, b = rec.split(":")
         wrt += a + ":" + str(int(float(b)*100)) + "|" #Concatenating results together.
      wrt += "\n"
   out_file.write(wrt)
```

**Output:**

```
s12,NONE,s11:172|s17:172|s14:67|s10:67|s19:67|s13:67|
s14,NONE,s13:449|s11:172|s17:172|s12:67|
```

Comment: you know you can iterate over a file object?

Comment: Yeah, got a little redundant there.

Answer (score 0):

split on the `|`, unpack, cast to float mult * 100 and call int:

```
import csv
with open("in.csv") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="|")
    for row in r:
        temp = ""
        for sub in row:
            try:
                a, b = sub.split(":")
                temp += "{}:{}|".format(a, int(float(b) * 100))
            except ValueError as e:
                continue
        print(temp)
```

Output:

```
s12,NONE,s11:172|s17:172|s14:67|s10:67|s19:67|s13:67|
s14,NONE,s13:449|s11:172|s17:172|s12:67|
```

`dir="."` keeps the tmpfile in the current directory so we can use it later, `delete=False` makes sure the file is not deleted when we leave the `with` block then we just have to call move outside the `with` to replace the original file with the updated.

Or use a if to catch the empty string:

```
import csv
with open("in.csv") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="|")
    for row in r:
        temp = ""
        for sub in row:
            if sub:
                a, b = sub.split(":")
                temp += "{}:{}|".format(a, int(float(b) * 100))
        print(temp)
```

To change the original file, write to a [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), then use [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to replace the original:

```
import csv
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move
with open("in.csv") as f, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False) as out:
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="|")
    for row in r:
        temp = ""
        for sub in row:
            if sub:
                a, b = sub.split(":")
                temp += "{}:{}|".format(a, int(float(b) * 100))
        out.write(temp+"\n")
move(out.name,"in.csv")
```

in.csv after:

```
s12,NONE,s11:172|s17:172|s14:67|s10:67|s19:67|s13:67|
s14,NONE,s13:449|s11:172|s17:172|s12:67|
```

You could also write as you go by changing the loop:

```
with open("in.csv") as f, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False) as out:
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="|")
    for row in r:
        for sub in row:
            if sub:
                a, b = sub.split(":")
                out.write("{}:{}|".format(a, int(float(b) * 100)))
        out.write("\n")
 move(out.name,"in.csv")
```